# Display text and button should be inline

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to create input text with button. both sgould be inline into one dive
I am doing below html but not getting how to do css.

onclick i want copy that text of textbox. and textbox only readonly. its like a coupon code..

```
<div class="coupon_coode_custom"><input type="text" value="Hello World" id="myInput">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Copy text</button></div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999)
  document.execCommand("copy");
  alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
}
</script>
```

I need help only in how to design text and button should be inline.

for design purpose find image attached

[image]

Comment: Do you have any CSS code to share?

Comment: Go through a [w3schools CSS tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/css/) or an [MDN CSS tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS)

Comment: @Arthur Borba actually i was not working to much in css. in css just use .coupon_coode_custom{display:flex} .. so its come inine. But not getting proper as i want.. button{width: 104px;
    background: purple;
    color: white;} ........... #myInput{width: 250px;}

Comment: I don't uderstand, your problem was you couldn't get both inline, right? The "display: flex" does that...what else are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex-box is your friend. This is a very strong technology introduced with CSS. Refer to this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) to learn more about flex-box.

Anyway, I will try to give you some CSS code for prototyping below:

```
.coupon_coode_custom {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
}

.coupon_coode_custom input {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-right: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.coupon_coode_custom button {
  width: 40%;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #3bb371;
  border: 1px solid #3bb371;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Please, consider that I hard-coded the sizings which means they are not responsive but have static sizing values. This is what you should avoid.

Since, I am not aware of your whole project and to let you practice by yourself, I have produced the CSS codes above which you will need to improve with more dynamic values using percentage (%), em, rem, etc.

Refer to this [Codepen](https://codepen.io/00009115/pen/gOggmqg?editors=1100) to see how the code I shared works.